# Yii2 pagination listview PAGE params

Tags: yii2

is there any way to hide PAGE param in Yii2 pagination listview?

current is domain/(anyattribute)?page=2

output should be domain/(anyattribute)/2

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can hide it.  If you want to hide all of your param attributes then it is possible.

```
Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false]);
//your grid
Pjax::end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/pagination-pretty-urls/
It should solve your problem.

Comment: Same concept i wanna use in ListView. How to customize my listview default pagination URL?